# jquery-How to get the id set to a <tr> of table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to access the  id set to tr of table

`var idOfCurrGoal = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`

is not working

Please help me out
thanks

Comment: Can you add the surrounding code?

Comment: how does your markup look like ? What is $(this) in this context ?

Comment: If `this` is a `table` element, you probably need to use `find()` and possibly also `eq()`, as `closest()` only goes up, ie. looks for parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, to achieve what you need...

---

First, get all `tr` from your table:

```
var tr = $('table').children().find('tr');
```

Then you can do something with each `tr` and get any attribute like the `id`:

```
$.each(tr, function(index, value) {
  var idOfCurrGoal = $(this).attr('id');
  /* do something */
});
```

Or, when user clicks one `tr`, get the `id` or any attribute of the clicked `tr`:

*(By this way you don't need to care if `tr` is the `closest` one or not)*

**Modern jQuery versions:**

```
tr.on('click', function() {
   var idOfCurrGoal = $(this).prop('id');
   /* do something */
});
```

**Old jQuery versions:**

```
tr.click(function() {
   var idOfCurrGoal = $(this).attr('id');
   /* do something */
});
```

Hope this helps :-)